# Google API client security issues?

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I have created a website that requires the user to be logged in via Oauth2 using Google as the provider.
I am using [this](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client) as a vendor and I basically implemented it as they advise you to.

Basically the flow is:

- User enters secured page
- Script checks if there is a cookie with a token
- Token is send to be checked for validation
- When valid, continue
- When invalid, send back to login page
- After login the code that is returned is checked via ID token verification after which the idtoken is saved as a cookie
- This cookie is used to verify the user every page load (we're not using any other API calls, only page-load authentication)

Now this script has been audited and the auditor has marked this flow 'insecure'. Saying an attacker could steal the token and use it for their own benefits. I totally understand this.

However; how to prevent this? We need to save the code somewhere? The auditor gave two points of advise: Send the redirect parameters not only to the authorize endpoints but also to the token endpoints. Thing is; I believe I already do so?

I would appreciate it very much if someone can guide me on these security findings.

Authorize code (used on pages that requires the user to be logged in):

```
if(isset($_POST['Logout'])){
    setcookie($COOKIENAME, "", time() - 3600);
    header("Location: /login.php", true, 301); }

try {
    

    if (!isset($_COOKIE[$COOKIENAME])) {
        header("Location: /login.php", true, 301);
    }
    require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';
    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setAuthConfig('./clientInfo.json');

    $redirect_uri = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/login.php';
    $client->setRedirectUri($redirect_uri);
    $client->setAccessType('offline');

    $token = $client->verifyIdToken($_COOKIE[$COOKIENAME]);
    if (!$token) {
        header("Location: login.php", true, 301); 
    } 
} catch (Exception $e) {
    print "An error occurred: " . $e->getMessage();
}
```

Authentication code (used for the callback):

```
if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setAuthConfig('./clientInfo.json');

    $redirect_uri = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/login.php';
    $client->setRedirectUri($redirect_uri);
    $client->setAccessType('offline');
    try {
        $token = $client->verifyIdToken(urldecode($_GET['code']));
        if ($token) {
            $userid = $token['sub'];

            $exp = $token['exp'];
            $cookie_name = $COOKIENAME;
            $cookie_value = urldecode($_GET['code']);
            setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_value, $exp, "/");
            header("Location: dashboard.php");
        } else {
            echo "invalid token";
        }
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        print "An error occurred: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
} else {
    echo "invalid token";
}
```

Comment: Looks like you are not actually storing the token in the cookie, but the `code`. Not sure why you would be doing that in the first place - a `code` parameter can only be exchanged for a token _once_, attempting to do it a second time should give you an error. What you should be storing, is the actual token - but not in a client-side cookie, of course, but in the session on the server side.

Comment: (And stop using `urldecode` on $_GET entries - PHP _has_ already decoded those for you, when it parsed the query string and populated $_GET.)

Comment: _"The auditor gave two points of advise: Send the redirect parameters not only to the authorize endpoints but also to the token endpoints. Thing is; I believe I already do so?"_ - yes, looks like you are. I can only assume that they were referring to the `redirect_uri` parameter - and that is _mandatory_ for the exchange-code-for-token endpoint, if you did not pass it or it was a value that was different from the one used in the login dialog request, then that would only have given you an error.

Comment: Was the "auditor" (whoever that may be?) specific about how they think the access token could be stolen? Or are they actually talking about that initial one-time code? That would have minimal value to anyone. But either way there should be no reason to put any tokens of any sort into cookies.

Comment: Everyone thanks for your responses. @ADyson how would you suggest to store the tokens? In memory has also been disputed as far as I can read online. The auditor is concerned the token (access token) can be stolen by using apps such as Burp Suite.

Comment: @CBroe Thanks for your tip on the urldecode. I am storing the access token. I will follow up on the tip to store it in session storage. And indeed; I am already using the redirect_uri everywhere so it's my guess what the auditor is aiming at...

Comment: It certainly needs to be stored server-side. Could be in the Session, or for a bit more security maybe in a (suitably protected) database.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [session](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php) instead of cookie to store the token.

Cookie is stored in client browser and is sent every time when communicating with server. Hacker can inject code on browser to steal it. They can also intercept the communication between server and client (if unencrypted) to steal it.

Session stores data on server side. Only a session ID is stored on browser. Hacker cannot get the data on browser because it is never sent to them.

```php
// This line is required to start using session.
session_start();

if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setAuthConfig('./clientInfo.json');

    $redirect_uri = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/login.php';
    $client->setRedirectUri($redirect_uri);
    $client->setAccessType('offline');
    try {
        $token = $client->verifyIdToken($_GET['code']);
        if ($token) {

            // Store both the code and verified token, if needed.
            $_SESSION['google_code'] = $_GET['code'];
            $_SESSION['google_code_token'] = $token;

            // TODO: Perhaps to use session_get_cookie_params() to set the expiration
            //       or setup other method to validate the token before use.

            header("Location: dashboard.php");
        } else {
            echo "invalid token";
        }
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        print "An error occurred: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
} else {
    echo "invalid token";
}
```